# PHP and MySQL SESSION, taking last row

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm showing a data table from MySQL, let say in x.php like

```
    <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      $id=$row["id"]; 
         echo "<tr><td>". $row["0"]. "</td><td>". $row["1"]."</td><td>".$row["2"]."</td><td>".$row["3"]."</td><td>"."<a href='y.php?=$id'>More details</a>"."</td></tr>";
        $_SESSION["id"]=$id;

     }
} else {
}?>
```

But where I go to y.php class  to see more details it shows data only from last row of MySQL records.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I only see one `$row`. Do you have a loop? How about a query?

Comment: `select ... order by something desc limit 1`, then you only ever display the one row.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php, to return to the start of the data SET mysql_data_seek

Comment: @volkinc Those functions [are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: show us the code you are using. From 2 lines of HTML it's difficult to offer you proper solution

Comment: You're replacing the session variable each time through the loop. When the loop is done, it will contain the ID from the last row.

Comment: @Barmar Upps,yes you're right thanks.But can you tell how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is you are using the $_SESSION to fetch the detail.
What you want isn't to store the id in the $_SESSION, you want to put it in each link, so that when a user clicks a link he has access to the row detail.

Basically, parameters passed in a link (like index.php?param1=value1) are found in `$_GET` global variable.

So I guess in y.php you use `$_SESSION['id']` to fetch the row detail, use `$_GET['id']` instead.

Also, in x.php edit this :

```
"<a href='y.php?=$id'>More details</a>"
```

to :

```
"<a href='y.php?id=$id'>More details</a>"
```

And remove : `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;`